# How to load angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started using angular and javascript and I can't really figure out how to structure my application.

I started writing a Controller and my first reflex is to put what I would call my model into a class in a different file. 
I have different option

1 - putting everything (model + controller )  in one file

2 - using requireJS so my controller can 'include' my model. I've managed to do it, put it wasn't straight forward and I still have problem to make the yeoman dist version to work.

3 - use angular module, which seems to be the recommended way, but if choose this solution do I need to load explicitly my model file in the main html file. I understand that not hardcoding the dependency between files can be a good thing, so you can for example swap or change some components, but it seems wrong when for example a subclass need to requires its parent class.  If I need to split a  module in lots of angular submodules, do I need to load them all explicitly ? That's seem totally wrong.

Am I missing something ? what is the standard way to do so ?

Comment: Yes, from personal experience this can be a pain with Angular, but is more a tooling/workflow issue than angular-centric. I've had success using grunt to automatically concatenate all js files in my app directory etc.. but for development have been manually linking the required files in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

What I found quite useful are the MTV meetup sessions. They give a good overview about how to apply best practices in AngularJS:

- **Best Practices**: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY
- **Angular+Yeoman**: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOmwZopzcTA

There are many more videos on youtube. I hope this helps giving a first idea.

Comment: I don't have time to watch videos, what do they say which could help me then ?